# RHEL 6.4 Kicking off all Terminal Connections

Tags: redhat, java

I have a RHEL 6.4 server with 64GB of ram running a java app that loads 60+ war files into tomcat.  For some reason, every time it loads every user gets kicked off.  This includes a directly connected monitor on the physical server.

The server is not generating any type of crash log but it is not possible to log in.  There still appears to be disk activity based on the disk lights.

I'm trying to determine if this application is the cause or merely just a symptom of some underlying hardware/software issue.  Anecdotally, I can say it only happens with this app.  Even running memtest86 showed no memory errors and a stress test getting the load to 160 with 100% memory usage did not crash.

My two questions are these:

1. Is there a process to monitor that would terminate any and all connections (remember this includes the VGA port on the physical server)
2. Are there any tools that would allow me to "wrap" this application and see exactly what point the terminations occur?

EDIT:  Did not find out why connections were being severed.  However, I moved the physical drives to another server (same hardware) and the issue does not happen on the new box.  Leads me to believe there is hardware issue somewhere.

Comment: Which user is the java process running as?

Comment: The process is running as root

Comment: Is it possible to run it as an unprivileged user? That would at least isolate the impact of whatever causes the other users to be logged off. Others will probably advise on the wisdom of running such a thing as root.

Comment: Are you sure the system isn't running out of memory? You could find this logged in _/var/log/messages_.

Comment: There is nothing in the /var/log/messages related to memory.  In addition, I have run a shell script running free every five seconds that shows the following:

Mem:      32879072    8615180   24263892          0     128760    3731152
-/+ buffers/cache:    4755268   28123804
Swap:     67108856          0   67108856
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:      32879072    8582016   24297056          0     128820    3664440
-/+ buffers/cache:    4788756   28090316

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try attaching a strace to one of the login shells, and then sending the trace to a file, and throw it in the background. That was it doesn't get caught hopefully.

something like:

```
PID=''
FILE_OUT=''
strace -D -t -f -v -p ${PID} -o ${FILE_OUT}
```

This way you can hopefully see what signal/command it's getting that's causing it to shutdown

Now that I think about it, I would throw an strace on one of the logins, but also the java app. You can much up the timestamps to see what happened right before/after in both threads.

Comment: Just an fyi to anyone interested, it turns out that the vendor application had a bug that was using up all resources.  Since the app could only be run as root, this caused everything to become non-responsive.